# How to display JAVA logger print out to C# console

Tags: java, c#

I am trying to display the information that is printed out in the command prompt from JAVA console to C#. It works fine when a System.out.println is issued in JAVA however it does not work with logger.info print out.

Note: When i run it through windows command prompt (CMD > java -jar testbed.jar) the logger info is printed out in the command prompt.

Appreciate inputs and help from anyone on this. A test code that i'm working is as follow:

JAVA to do a simple increment and decrement number and print out through a logger when a button is pressed to increment or decrement. (THIS CODE CANNOT BE CHANGED)

```
private static int ValueInteger = 0 ;
static Logger l;

public TestBed() {
        initComponents();
        try{
            l = Logger.getLogger("");
            FileHandler fh = new FileHandler("main.log", false);
            l.addHandler(fh);
            l.setLevel(Level.ALL);
            l.fine("Logger Created - JTSRunner.main()");
        }catch(Exception ex){}
    }
 private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        ValueInteger--;         
//        System.out.println(Integer.toString(ValueInteger));
        l.info(Integer.toString(ValueInteger));
    } 

 private void jButton4ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        ValueInteger++; 
//        System.out.println(Integer.toString(ValueInteger));
        l.info(Integer.toString(ValueInteger));
    }
```

C# code to handle and print out onto a textbox (CODE THAT I'M WORKING ON):

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd", "/k java -jar Testbed.jar ")
        {
            WorkingDirectory = "C:\\Testbed",
            WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden,
            UseShellExecute = false,
            RedirectStandardOutput = true,
            CreateNoWindow = true
        };

        Process process = Process.Start(startInfo);
        process.OutputDataReceived += writeCommandInfo;
        process.BeginOutputReadLine();           
        //process.WaitForExit();
    }

    private void writeCommandInfo(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Data != null)
        {
            this.Text.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => this.Text.Text = e.Data.ToString()), DispatcherPriority.Normal, null);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Add a console appender to the logger.

Comment: I can't change the JAVA code. I'm working only on C# code. Will add that to my questions\

Answer (score 0):

The default `java.util.logging` properties file configures ConsoleHandler which logs messages to `System.err` ([source](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/logging/ConsoleHandler.java)), and that's why the messages appear in the command prompt. But since your C# code only redirects standard out and not the standard error (`RedirectStandardError`), the process isn't able to capture the messages.

Try setting the `RedirectStandardError` property to true.